# C# работа через Socket и с БД MS Access

Tags: access, сокет, c#

Как организовать работу с сокетом? Перечитал кучу разных статей, но они там только для простенького чата сделаны, а я делаю игру клиент-сервер и, собственно, для передачи данных надо использовать именно сокет. А так же, меня интересует как подключать и работать в дальнейшем с базой данный Access.

Comment: @Veizdem, по сокетам, раскройте вопрос более подробно. Например, почему вы не используете "хорошо известные объекты", а решили делать на сокетах?

Comment: Поставлена задача сделать это все на сокетах, мотивация этого была, цитирую: "маленький объем данных при передаче". Что касается того, что нужно передавать - абсолютно все обрабатывается на сервере, а клиенту передаются все эти параметры, вплоть до параметров, например button1.text, при этом эта кнопка находится на клиенте, а значение параметра - отправляет сервер.

Comment: Так, и что вам пояснить? Или вы ищете хорошую статью по сокетам?

Comment: Да, я ищу хорошую, максимально понятную и полную статью по сокетам и статью по работе с БД Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если говорить о сокетах в .NET, то есть достаточно хорошая [статья на MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/Rus/Msdn/Magazine/2005/08/Winsock.mspx).

Comment: Спасибо, но хотелось бы побольше примеров... Я в первую очередь MSDN пересмотрел...